# What is the word for number "0"?

Tags: numbers

Unus, -a, -um means number "1". What is the word for number "0"?

https://www.translate.com/english-latin says it is nulla. Is it correct?

Comment: This is a really good question! Thank you for your excellent posts on Latin StackExchange.

Answer (score 21):

Classical Latin does not have a word for, or a concept of, “zero”. Fibonacci in about 1200 used the term zephirum, a transcription of Arabic ṣifr “empty”, then “zero” as a calque on Sanskrit śūnya “empty, zero”.

Comment: It's a minor nitpick but śunya should be śūnya (vowel length is phonemic in Sanskrit and traditionally always marked). Śunya is listed in Monier-Williams' dictionary as a variant but quotable only from Sanskrit dictionaries and word lists

Comment: @Au101. Thanks. Typo corrected.

Comment: *Zephirum*, of course, eventually entered English as *cypher*.

Answer (score 12):

Just an addendum, but you can translate "zero" as *nullus, -a, -um* when it's used in sentences like, "I have zero pigs." The Romans would say: *nullos porcos habeo.*

But in English, it's no different from saying, "I have no pigs."

Answer (score 9):

> https://www.translate.com/english-latin says it is nulla. Is it correct?

**No, it isn't**. *Nulla* is classical Latin for nothing. It's one thing that the Romans could've used *instead of* the number *zero* but it's not the actual number itself. *Nihil* and *nihilum* would be other go-tos.

**In New Latin, the default is variants of *cipher***: [cifra](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cifra#Latin), [cifera](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cifera#Latin), [ciphra](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ciphra#Latin), [cyphra](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/60550119.pdf) (in Euler), [chifra, zifra, ziffra, zifera, ziphera](http://www.koeblergerhard.de/wikiling/index.php?f=latin&page=1940), &c. There's also [zephirum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zephirum#Latin)

> **1202**, Leonardo Fibonacci, *Liber Abaci*, Cap. I:
>
> > Cum his itaque novem figuris, et cum hoc signo 0, quod arabice **zephirum** appellatur, scribitur quilibet numerus, […]
> >
> > > With these nine figures, and with this sign 0, which is called **zero** in Arabic, any number can be written, […]

and [zerum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zerum) if you want *zero* to show up in the dative and ablative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146775/discussion-between-cmw-and-lly).

Comment: There are options A, B, C, D. There is also option E... if you want for something to happen. That thing... you might want to happen... is _zero_ showing up as the _Latin_ dative and ablative.

Comment: @cmw To me "the form _zerō_ shows up in the paradigm of _zerum_" vel sim is entirely fine. (Similarly, as your example, "this form shows up in Vergil" or "this form shows up in Late Latin".)

Comment: @Draconis If only that was said, there'd be no confusion!

Comment: @Draconis: I didn't quite understand the sentence as it was phrased at first, so I had the same question as CMW. I now understand it, and so I have edited it for clarity, pace Ily.

Comment: Latin Wikipedia uses the masculine "zerus", attested in some technical contexts

Comment: @KotobaTrilyNgian Fwiw, [it's not on the English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zerus) or [Latin Wiktionary](https://la.wiktionary.org/wiki/zerus). [The Vicapaedia entry on _zero_](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/0) does use it as the _main_ form of the name with two 18th century cites but that seems more like amplifying a mistake than anything else. (Then again... sure... The word was originally borrowed from Arabic anyway. Why _not_ reborrow it from English too?)

Comment: Seems like it was originally _cifra_ but [this editor changed it with a cite](https://la.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=0&direction=next&oldid=2828001) and then no one ever changed it back. It has been left alone for 8 years now. Maybe this discussion will inspire someone to go fix it. xD Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

The Latin word "nulla" is a good choice for translating the English word "zero". Here are some reasons:

1. The Latin word "nulla" is attested in many ancient documents (as far back as the 6th century AD) to mean the number zero.
2. The word "null" in computer science derives from the Latin word "nulla". The word "null" in computer science has been used to mean the value 0. It gets used in many contexts, like null pointers, null-terminated strings, and null references.
3. The word "nulla" is a combination of "ne-" (not) and "ulla" (any), and it can mean "no one, none, not any, zero".
4. For over one thousand years, the symbol N has been used to mean zero, and it stands for the Latin words "nulla" or "nihil". The letter N is still used today to mean 0 in many professions.

That said, I think there are many other options for translating the English word "zero" into Latin. The word "nulla" is a common choice and it is attested in many ancient and modern documents.

Comment: Which profession (or language) uses "N" regularly to mean zero?

Comment: Neither WIktionary nor the OED acknowledge such an abbreviation.